# Do I need external IP for Tor Node?

Tags: configuration, relays

after reading articles about tor and how it works-Tor Node too. i want to create my own Tor Node and transfer to my Node my data from the browsing.
I'm using VMware Workstation with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
this is my `torrc` file, copy, paste from tor site:

```
Nickname test
ORPort 443
ExitRelay 0
SocksPort 0
ControlSocket 0
ContactInfo human@gmail.com
```

after running in the terminal the `tor` commend I'm getting messages that its running well and its 
`bootstrapped 100%`

`[notice] Now checking whether ORPort xx.xxx.xxx.x:443 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)`

here the error messages starts:

```
[notice] Your network connection speed appears to have changed. Resetting timeout to 60s after 18 timeouts and 100 buildtimes.

[warn] Your server (xx.xxx.xxx.x:443) has not managed to confirm that its ORPort is reachable. Relays do not publish descriptors until their ORPort and DirPort are reachable. Please check your firewalls, ports, address, /etc/hosts file, etc.
```

i dont know how to handle this error message after a long search what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the TorRelayGuide. It is very very useful. https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide

From [this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide#OSLevelConfiguration) section:

> If you are using a firewall, open a hole in your firewall so incoming connections can reach the ports you will use for your relay (ORPort, plus DirPort if you enabled it). Also, make sure you allow all outgoing connections too, so your relay can reach the other Tor relays, clients and destinations. You can find the specific ORPort TCP port number in the torrc configuration samples bellow (in the OS specific sections).

You need to tell your router to forward a port to the machine running VMWare. Then you probably need to tell VMWare to forward the same port to the Ubuntu VM.